# How to get values from complex Object return from Socket IO server in android java

Tags: java, android, json, node.js, socket.io

While working with android Socket.io nodejs server...

Server returns a list of users data

```
    private Emitter.Listener onSyncdData = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                   
                    try {
                        Gson gson=new Gson();
                        String json = gson.toJson(args);
```

json string contains

```
[{"values":
[{"nameValuePairs":{"Name":"Varun","EmailAddress":"","Latitude":"12","Langitude":"12","IsYours":"false","MobileNumber":"(903) 011-7411"}},
{"nameValuePairs":{"Name":"Varun","EmailAddress":"","Latitude":"12","Langitude":"12","IsYours":"false","MobileNumber":"(905) 970-8111"}},
{"nameValuePairs":{"Name":"Viany","EmailAddress":"","Latitude":"12","Langitude":"12","IsYours":"false","MobileNumber":"(900) 094-3111"}},
{"nameValuePairs":{"Name":"Pavan","EmailAddress":"","Latitude":"12","Langitude":"12","IsYours":"false","MobileNumber":"(779) 981-3111"}},
{"nameValuePairs":{"Name":"Rakesh","EmailAddress":"","Latitude":"12","Langitude":"12","IsYours":"false","MobileNumber":"(800) 895-3111"}},
{"nameValuePairs":{"Name":"","EmailAddress":"","Latitude":"12","Langitude":"12","IsYours":"true","MobileNumber":"15555215554"}}
]}]
```

My Question is how can i retrieve "Name","EmailAddress","MobileNumber"..etc from json or args object.

Comment: If you want to read a JSON, the GSON method is called `fromJson`

Answer (score 1):

Gson takes in JsonElement but not JSONObject(org.json). So you need to do as follows in your code so that you don't get the nameValuePairs:

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)args[0];//be sure to org.json but not com.google.gson 
PrasingClass parsingClass = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(),PrasingClass.class);
```

to parse it correct without nameValuePairs.